# Как перевести готовую верстку, уже натянутую на wordpress с помощью Polylang или других плагинов?

Tags: wordpress, polylang

Здраствуйте!
Натянул сайт на WP, хочу перевести сайт на другие языки, но не знаю как это сделать с помощью Polylang.
Подскажите, как реализовать это.
Спасибо!

Comment: Документация Polylang нормальная - читайте, разбирайтесь. Если что-то не получается - задавайте новый вопрос т.к. текущий слишком общий

Comment: https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/
Посмотрите обязательно функции, чтобы не изобретать велосипед в коде